# System.AccessViaolation while executing Bulk Insert (Oracle.DataAccess)

Tags: c#, oracle, access-violation

I am facing a severe problem concerning an winforms application. I am inserting via oracle bulk insert (ArrayBinding) into a table. While executing the Command with

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

I get the following Error:

`System.AccessViolationException
  at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OpsErr.FreeCtx(IntPtr& opsErrCtx)
  at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.GetOpoErrCtx(IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, IntPtr opsConCtx, String dataSrc, String procedure)
  at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException..ctor(IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, IntPtr opsConCtx, String dataSrc, String procedure)
  at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleErrorHelper(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, String procedure)
  at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleError(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, String procedure, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src)
  at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()`

Any ideas on this issue?

MacX

Comment: Also which version are you targetting 2.0, 3.5 ? I believe you might be missing some patches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the issue myself.

The Oracle.DataAccess.Client seems not be able to correctly notify me, that on of the column values exceeds the limit of the database column i want to insert the value.

Something like inserting "hello my friend" in a varhchar2(2)-column.

But thanks for looking at this.